# python meshgrid values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mesh

**Solved**

I've a pandas DataFrame like this

```
       X    Y       Z      Vx           Vy              Vz
0   -17.5   10.0   2.5     0.037132     -4.021866e-02   -0.002117
1   -17.5   12.5   0.0     0.021691     -3.838874e-02   -0.000651
3   -17.5   0.0    12.5    0.063864     7.724853e-07    -0.023265
7   -17.5   2.5    2.5     0.072648     -1.244435e-02   -0.002749
16  -17.5   5.0    0.0     0.064299     -2.709658e-02   -0.000972
```

and I'd like to plot a 3D quiver plot where X,Y,Z are the cartesian coordinates and Vx,Vy,Vz are the components of my vectorial field.
I've made the meshgrid for the x,y,z in such way

```
x,y,z = np.meshgrid(dataPM[dataPM.columns[0]],dataPM[dataPM.columns[1]],dataPM[dataPM.columns[2]])
```

but I'm struggling in making a function for creating the corresponding meshgrid for the Vx,Vy,Vz.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It looks like your data is already gridded. So you just need to reshape your columns.

Comment: I've tried in this way 
 `u,v,w = np.meshgrid(dataPM[dataPM.columns[3]],dataPM[dataPM.columns[4]],dataPM[dataPM.columns[5]])`
but the plt.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w) behaves in a wired way and it plots for each xyz point the resulting vector but all the three components (u, v, w)

Comment: As said, it would not make sense to create a meshgrid here at all, but rather reshape your columns to a grid.

Comment: Thanks or the hint, I've uploaded my solution.

Comment: Please do not answer a question within the question. Instead answer it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

It turns out that in case you already have a pandas DataFrame with all the x,y,z,Vx,Vy,Vz values you can just pass them to the quiver, my fault but as usual the more you try the more you learn.

So the final code was:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(dataPM[dataPM.columns[0]], dataPM[dataPM.columns[1]], dataPM[dataPM.columns[2]],dataPM[dataPM.columns[3]],dataPM[dataPM.columns[4]],dataPM[dataPM.columns[5]])
plt.show()
```

And then if you want to get it nicer you can play with the colours and so on.

Thanks to everyone